# Constructor on Generic Class has Invalid Arguments

Tags: c#, generics, async-await

I'm looking to use the tips from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2014/11/17/code-coverage-with-async-await.aspx) to push the code coverage on a project of mine closer to 100%.  Specifically the last section which outlines an idea for a workaround to methods I don't control or otherwise can't inject.  The non-generic `Task` version given in the article works like a charm, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting a generic `Task<T>` version to work.

It's likely that I'm just missing something obvious.

My awaiter (with debug flags removed for brevity) is:

```
public class EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly TaskAwaiter<T> taskAwaiter;

    private bool forceAsync;

    public EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter(Task<T> task)
    {
        this.taskAwaiter = task.GetAwaiter();
        this.forceAsync = true;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.forceAsync)
                return false;
            return this.taskAwaiter.IsCompleted;
        }
    }

    public T GetResult()
    {
        this.forceAsync = false;
        return this.taskAwaiter.GetResult();
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        this.forceAsync = false;
        this.taskAwaiter.OnCompleted(continuation);
    }
}
```

And my awaitable is:

```
public class EnsureCodeCoverageAwaitable<T>
{
    private Task<T> _task;

    public EnsureCodeCoverageAwaitable(Task<T> task)
    {
        _task = task;
    }

    public EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>()
    {
        return new EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter<T>(_task);
    }
}
```

The problem, according to the compiler, is on that last line in the `GetAwaiter<T>` method.  The compiler tells me:

> The best overloaded method match for EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter(Task<T>) has some invalid arguments

If I use Visual Studio's tooling to "generate constructor stub" from that same line, it generates a second constructor in `EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter` with the exact same signature as the existing one, and the error remains.  (I can continue to use the same tooling to generate more and more identical constructor stubs.)

When I look at the intellisense while building that line of code, the constructor says it expects a `Task<T>` and the variable I'm passing it claims to be of type `Task<T>`.

Did I miss something about generics here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>()
```

You don't want that to be a generic method introducing a new type parameter `T` - you just want to use the type parameter of the type. So you want:

```
public EnsureCodeCoverageAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter()
```

The compiler should have given you a warning about this:

> CS0693: Type parameter `'T'` has the same name as the type parameter from outer type `'EnsureCoverageAwaitable<T>'`

Always check compiler warnings :)

Comment: The "old" compiler (VS2010, .NET 4) also gives a warning: `Warning - Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'Foo<T>'`

Comment: @Styxxy: Doh!  My various panes auto-hide (to maximize editor space), so I didn't even think to look for a warning.  Just the in-line error in the editor.  :)

Comment: @David: I typically set warnings as errors, to make it hard to ignore them :)

Comment: When one ignores the compiler warning and uses `T` in two meanings like this, is there a way to refer to the "outer" `T` from within the generic method (or from within the nested generic type in a related scenario)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Not that I'm aware of.